# Polynomials with negative exponents in Python

Tags: python, numpy, polynomial-math

Is there a library to work with polynomial arithmetic when polynomials can have negative exponents? I found the [poly1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) class in numpy, but I cannot figure out how I could represent a polynomial like `x**-3 + x**-2 + x**2 + x**3`.

Comment: Just multiply everything by the x raised to the absolute value of the largest negative exponent and use the normal polynomial class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, a polynomial is an expression of finite length constructed from variables (also called indeterminates) and constants, using only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and **non-negative integer** exponents.

What you're asking about isn't a polynomial -- for example polynomials are always finite, but what you want has a singularity at 0.  On the positive side, there are libraries for symbolic manipulation.  Take a look at [sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/).

Comment: Thank you for the definition. Now I understand why polynomial classes work like this. And David Zwicker comment tell me how I should do.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the [Law of Exponents](http://brownmath.com/alge/expolaws.htm) ([archived link](https://archive.ph/PXekA)), to shift the exponent to the bottom of a fraction and make it positive:

This:

```
print (5**-2)
print (1.0/(5**2))
```

Yields:

```
0.04
0.04
```