# Transforming polynomial variable in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, symbolic-math, polynomial-math

I am trying to learn how to use Numpy. Consider I have the roots of a polynomial. I use 
`coeff = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfromroots(roots)` 
to get the coefficients of the polynomial as an array. Then I use
 `print  np.poly1d(coeff)`
To print out the polynomial. Let that polynomial be

> x^2 +3x + 2

Now how do I transform the variable such that

> x is now 2/x

That is the equation becomes

> (2/x)^2 + 6/x + 2

In scilab I can do this using the horner function. Is it possible in numpy?

Comment: perhaps you want to use Sympy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SymPy this would be simply:

```
from sympy.abc import x

f = x**2 + 3*x + 2
g = f.subs({x:2/x})
```

Resulting in:

```
print(g)
#2 + 6/x + 4/x**2
```

Answer (score 0):

The resulting expression [is not a polynomial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433477/polynomials-with-negative-exponents-in-python), and [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/index.html) would probably be a better choice here.

Alternatively you can just scale the coefficients of the polynomial by the appropriate numerical factor,

```
coeff *= np.power(factor, np.arange(len(coefs)-1, -1, -1))   # factor=2 here
```

and then use the polynomial functions from numpy, with the variable `1/x` instead of `x`.

Comment: Thank you Saullo and rth. I'll look into sympy.

Comment: @taz I added an answer using SymPy